# How to use android ContactsContract.Data

Tags: android, android-contacts

I am working on an IM application in android. Now i created a separate table for maintaining the app contacts. In this case my contacts are difficult to manage when there is a change in contacts of android system. For avoiding this I found to use a Sync Adapter with ContactsContract provider. I referred the [developer document](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html) for managing the contacts. I found how to create account, raw contact on an existing contact. Now what i need is how to have my columns(Presence[String],subscription status[integer], etc.) on ContactsContract.Data. I know I have to create my own DataKinds, but I don't know how to. So please give me some solutions to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I found how to keep status, presence details in ContactsContract.Data by this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.StatusUpdates.html)...